# How to add distinct items into spinner from DB in android

Tags: android

i need to upload unique data from DB into spinner list in android.Ex.In my DB i have 4 records as "Jan","Feb","Mar","Jan".i need to upload those data in to spinner by distinct.i.e.only jan,feb,mar.
How could i do this?

My code...
 //...

```
 Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);

 AdapterCountries = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 AdapterCountries.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spin.setAdapter(AdapterCountries);
 spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener());

 db1.open();
 // long id;

 Cursor cursor = db1.getAllTitles1();
 while (cursor.moveToNext()){
   results=cursor.getString(2);
   AdapterCountries.add(results);
 }
 db1.close();
```

In My DBAdapter class..

```
public Cursor getAllTitles1(){

 return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] {

            KEY_ROWID,DISHNAME,CATEGORY,DESCRIPTION},null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `DISTINCT` clause in the the sql query, and it will return unique data already.

Use raw queries in `execute` method, instead of using the current approach.

Comment: I used as u told..But it fails..Thats why i posted on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method for getting distinct values.